# Qt installer framework reading text file for installation path

Tags: qt, frameworks, qt-installer

I'm creating an installer and I need to have functionality to read a text file and get some installation params. Specifically, I need to read an installation path from a text file. I was trying to use FileReader from JS, but I can't figure out how it could be used inside the `Controller.prototype.TargetDirectoryPageCallback` function. Maybe there is  easier approach to do that? Any working sample maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The script context has only a few objects.

- console
- QFileDialog
- print
- qsTr
- systemInfo
- QInstaller
- buttons
- QMessageBox
- QDesktopServices
- installer
- gui

The "installer" object is the most important one (see http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#execute-method).
With the help of this execute method you can run any application on your system. So here my untested code suggestion:

```
if (installer.value("os") == "win") {
  var windir = installer.environmentVariable("WINDIR");
  if (windir == "")
    print("Could not find windows installation directory.");
  var cmdLocation = windir + "\\system32\\cmd.exe";
var fileContent = installer.execute(cmdLocation, new Array("/c", "type", <your_file>))[0];
```

Yes this is not very comfortable - so maybe you should create a feature request or add this kind of functionality to the installer framework.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Installer Framework 3.x:

`string readFile(string filePath, string codecName)`